# Padding of Text breaks out of Parent Container (display:inline)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, text-alignment

I have a component which has some text with some padding that aligns with the text, so it will look like this:

[image]

I want the padding to align with the text (as you can see in the image) and I'm happy with this. I achieve this with this component:

```
const StyledPlainText = styled.div`
    line-height: 1.7;

    span {
        display: inline;

        padding: 1.5rem 3rem;

        /* Needs prefixing */
        box-decoration-break: clone;
        -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    }
`;
```

and then use it like this:

```
<StyledPlainText>
  <span>{text}</span>
</StyledPlainText>;
```

But as you can see in the picture, the text break out of its parent at the word `not`. I am not sure why this is. This makes the text look not centered, though it technically is.

When I change the `display: inline;` to `display: block;` I can avoid it breaking out, but then I lose the aligned padding and it will look like this (which is what I don't want):

[image: Don't want this]

Any idea of how I can avoid the text breaking out without changing `display: inline` or at least keeping this padding which aligns with the text?

Comment: do u tried display:inline-block; ??

Comment: @DrJManish yes, that gives me the same result as `display: block;` unfortunately.